# Are there publicly available general protocols?

Tags: scientific-method, general-practitioners

Are there published books which detaild recommended or well known protocols of the type used by general practitioners?

I know that doctors typically develop protocols for their own offices, but on what do they base these? Is there some standard source that details usual protocols?

Comment: What has your research found so far?